# Should I remove all authentication code from my User model since a have the Identity model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I just came across [omniauth-identity](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-identity) which enables users to sign in and register without using a Facebook, Twitter, etc.

There is a step were you have to create a `Identity` model (I'm following this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/304-omniauth-identity)):

```
class Identity < OmniAuth::Identity::Models::ActiveRecord

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence:   true,
                format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
end
```

Now, I already have an `User` model and a login and registration system (created by following the [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book)):

**user.rb:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  has_secure_password

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  before_save :create_remember_token

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence:   true,
                    format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

  private

  def create_remember_token
   self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end
```

So I'm a bit confused. Should remove the lines that have to do with authentication in the `User` model (e.g. validation, `attr_accesible`, `create_remember_token` etc. along with the `name` and `email` fields in the users table)?

And remove **sessions_helper.rb** too?

```
module SessionsHelper
  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

  def signed_in_user
    unless signed_in?
      store_location
      redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
    end
  end

  def redirect_back_or(default)
    redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
    session.delete(:return_to)
  end

  def store_location
    session[:return_to] = request.url
  end
end
```

Because, correct me if I'm wrong, but I I think `omniauth-identity` handles that too (except for the `current_user` part.

Comment: User is a User. It's for you. Your app. (Or, this is how I would recommend using it). The other model (ie. Identity) is not. It is just a means to an end. That is, here is a good chance to separate "User information" from "Identification and authentication". In this case all the tutorial stuff has been superseded in the latter case and only represents duplicate/old garbage - *that* should be removed.

Comment: @pst OK I see, but the `Identity` model seem to handle many things like validation and the `email` and `password` attributes. So I was wondering whether to keep that in the `User` model (e.g. removing the `attr_accesible` part)?

Comment: Is it being used or does it merely represent legacy code? If it *is* being used, does it *need* to be used? As that would imply a duplication of information. That is, go through a checklist. Argue for/against the points. I find writing it down helps.

Comment: @pst Well, the `Identity` model will store for example `name` and `email`. The `User` model already have them. Does it mean it is duplicate code and has to be removed from the `User` model?

Comment: Well, *is* there a reason to have it in both places? Go back to the checklist. (I would argue: "No". However, it might make sense to keep the User object and Proxy through the name, etc.)

Comment: @pst Thanks for helping. Well, I'm a bit confused, because I'm displaying stuff like this: `user.name` and `user.email` in my views. If I remove that form the users tables is not going to work.

Comment: Those values can be proxied through from an Identity - hopefully there is a User 1:1 Identity mapping in the model. So the SessionHelper/current_user still deals with User. The actual sign-up/sign-in code would validate off of Identities, which are in turned associated with a User.

Comment: @pst Sorry I'm a bit new to Rails. What do you mean by `User 1:1 Identity mapping`? You mean that the `Identity` model automatically recognizes the `User` model? Or I have to do that myself? (If so, how?)

Comment: No, I mean there /should/ be a User model (e.g. a User table) that has a 1:1 mapping with an Identity (e.g. Identity table). When an account is created there are two things - the Identity of the account (identification/authorization) and the User entity (represents other aspects of the user - e.g. gender or whatnot - and acts as a "bridge" with the rest of the model). The User object is what is associated with the other models. The Identity is /only/ associated with the User.

Comment: e.g. a User *has a [unique]* Identity and a User *has many* Galleries/Pictures/Posts (or whatever the site/model uses). An Identity *does not* have any Galleries/Pictures/Post, but an Identity *represents* a User and, here, *contains* identification/authentication information (name, email, password in this case, although the name could be viewed as part of the User).

Comment: @pst Oh, I think the assosiation is made by this?     `session[:user_id] = user.id` in the sessions controller? `So user.name` will work even if the user model doesn't have a name column?

Comment: No - you'll need to proxy the value over (but that's easy, because each User *has [or should have] a* Identity). So given a User, one can get an Identity and thus the name (and this can be hidden inside the User model - `class User; def name; return_the_name_from_identity_perhaps_with_caching; end end`). Likewise, on sign-in, the User (once again, created along with each Identity) is still used as it is in the current model. `current_user` should still return/take a User.

Comment: @pst but that's defined in **user.rb** `def .self.create_with_omniauth do user.name = auth["info"]["name"]` So that's enough?

Comment: It's hard to say without more context, but yes. Also see https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Managing-Multiple-Providers (I said 1:1 mapping, but following a 1:M mapping shown in the link is ultimately more flexible - e.g. linked accounts). Also follow the link(s) in that page.

Answer (score 0):

Creating the Identity model is useful mostly to authenticate with multiple providers. Here's a good description of how to go about doing that:

https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Managing-Multiple-Providers

It answers your question what should be in the User model and what in the Identity model.